# How to use a ref in two different components in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

i have two components (Title and Input components) that should have the same title ref and when one is changed the other should also change. i tried what i did understand from this replies in [this discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/1889euj/is_event_bus_still_a_thing) but it didn't work. what i am missing?

Home.vue:

```
<template>
  <Title></Title>
  <Input></Input>
</template>

<script setup>
import Input from '../Components/Input.vue';
import Title from '../Components/Title.vue';
</script>
```

Title.vue:

```
<template>
  <h1 class="text-4xl font-bold">{{ title }}</h1>
</template>

<script setup>
import useTitles from '../composables/titles';

const { title } = useTitles();
</script>
```

Input.vue:

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="title">
  <button @click="change">submit</button>
</template>

<script setup>
import useTitles from '../composables/titles';

const { title } = useTitles();

const change = () => {
  title.value = 'title changed'
}

</script>
```

titles.js:

```
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default function useTitles() {
  const title = ref('Home')

  return { title }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composable functions don't work in an exceptional way themselves, it's the same as unwrapping the function, i.e. evaluating `ref('Home')` in each of these components, this results in `title` state not being shared between them.

If the intention is to share the state, it should be either [global state](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api):

```
// titles.js
export const title = ref('Home')
```

Or if there can be multiple states per app, the state needs to be provided to component hierarchy with `provide`/`inject`:

```
// Home.vue
const title = ref('Home')
provide('title', title)

// Title.vue
const title = inject('title')
```

Answer (score 0):

As was previously commented, there are multiple ways of going about this.
One of them being "global refs" (though afaik this is not a recommended approach).
Another is using provide/inject to share states across Child components down the tree. This is useful to avoid [Prop Drilling](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject#prop-drilling).

If `<Title>` and `<Input>` are direct children of `<Home>` you won't be running into prop drilling issues, so you could just rely on the good old `Props in, Events Out` way of handling this.

Just pass down the title as a prop to the components and if you need to be able to change the title in the input component, just use `@change="title = $event"`.

```html
<script setup>
// Home.vue
import Input from '../Components/Input.vue';
import Title from '../Components/Title.vue';

const title = ref('Hello World')

// or if you want to use a dedicate handler
function onTitleChange(newTitle) {
   title.value = newTitle
}
</script>

<template>
  <Title :title="title"></Title>

  <Input :title="title" @change=="title = $event"></Input>

  <!-- or using a dedicated handler -->
  <Input :title="title" @change=="onTitleChange"></Input>
</template>
```

```html
<script setup>
const props = defineProps(['title'])

const emits = defineEmits(['change'])

const currentTitle = ref(props.title)

const onChange = () => {
  emits('change', currentTitle.value)
}
</script>

<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="currentTitle">
  <button @click="onChange">submit</button>
</template>
```

But, as previously mentioned, the proposed solutions by Estus Flask also work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You create a new ref every time you call your composable, just move the ref to the global scope. Also there's nothing extremely wrong if you want to use composables for a global state, use them if you like.

```
const title = ref('Home')
export default function useTitles() {
  return { title }
}
```

You could also consider `provide/inject`.